# agora-rtm-sdk-1.5.0.js:8 RTM:ERROR Error Code 5: login failed with args

Tags: javascript, json, token

I am creating a website with the agora web **sdk**.
I import the sdk to my folder *js* and I write the script in *index.html*:

```
<script src="js/agora-rtm-sdk-1.5.0.js"></script>
```

My **code** is this, *room.js*:

```
let appID = StringAppId
let token= StringToken
let uid = String(Math.floor(Math.random() * 232))
let room = 'default'


let initiate = async () => {
    let rtmClient = await AgoraRTM.createInstance(appID)
    await rtmClient.login({ uid, token })

    const channel = await rtmClient.createChannel(room)
    await channel.join()

    channel.on('ChannelMessage', (messageData, memberId) => {
        let data = JSON.stringify(messageData.text)
        console.log('Data: ', data)
    })

    let sendMessage = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        let message = e.target.message.value
        channel.sendMessage({ text: JSON.stringify({ 'message': message }) })
        e.target.reset()
    }


    let messageForm = document.getElementById('message__form')
    messageForm.addEventListener('submit', sendMessage)
}

initiate()
```

The problem is that I get these **errors**:
[image]

Comment: i have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution to this issue... when you create the app in agora you want make sure that you select authentication by AppID only. as follows.
**Testing mode: AppID**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to use your app on production. You should setup a backend for token generation for security concern.

You are getting this error, because the generated user token and the client login userId is not validating and hence are getting `RtmUnauthenticatedError`.

Below code should help you fixing the error.

Server.js

`const userId = 12344567890`

`RtmTokenBuilder.buildToken(appID, cert, userId, rtmRole, privilegeExpiredTs)`

Client.js

`await rtmClient.login({ uid: userId, token })`